# Regarding showing a button when you hover over HTML table row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created an HTML table, with one column dedicated to a button that's invisible by default.  When you hover over a row, I have the corresponding button become visible.  This all works fine, and here's an example of the HTML and CSS.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><button  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm hidden-button">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden-button {
    opacity:0;
}

td:hover .hidden-button {
    opacity:1;
}
```

My question though, is why does this work?  I was experimenting, but completely expected all of the buttons with class .hidden-button to become visible.  Could someone take a second and explain to me why this is not the case? Thank you!

Comment: The only elements that satisfy the conditions of the selector (which is here the hover) will become visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td:hover .hidden-button` applies your `opacity: 1;` to elements with the `hidden-button` class nested under each given `td` that is in the `hover` state.

Comment: Perfect, simple explanation.  Don't know how this slipped my mind.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your below CSS code applying globally on all TD

```
td:hover .hidden-button {
opacity:1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`td:hover .hidden-button` actually refers to only the `hidden-button` which is present inside the td over which your mouse is hovering.  So only this one element will appear when your mouse hovers over the `td` element.

In CSS, you come to the class of parent to child by reading the code from left to right.

Answer (score -1):

The reason this works is because your specifically targeting ALL td elements inside of your html, so whenever you hover over a td, you target that td element of all td elements inside of the table.

```css
.box {
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:black;
margin:10px;
float:left
}

.box:hover {
background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1">1</div>
<div class="box box2">2</div>
```